# Base composable aspect ratio on current composable size

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way in jetpack compose to set composable ratio based on composable size? For example I have:

```
 Column(modifier = Modifier
      .wrapContentSize()
      .aspectRatio(1.3f)
```

In docs it says that aspect ratio is calculated with either Constraints.min or Constraints.max. Can I somehow adjust composable's ratio after it;s been wrapped with `wrapContentSize()`?

Answer (score 0):

There's the `onGloballyPositioned` Modifier, which provides the dimensions as well as the coordinates of a Composable.

So,

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf() }
Column(
 modifier = Modifier
               .wrapContentSize()
               .onGloballyPositioned { size = it.size }
               .aspectRatio(/* Calculate Based on size */)
)
```

should do the job, I guess.